# Can cache attacks be executed on a single thread architecture?

Tags: caching, side-channel

Despite an extensive research on the subject, I'm wondering if there exists side channel attacks based on cache use which are conducted on single threaded architecture, smart cards for instance.

I'm conscious that generally, when one talks about cache attack, the attacker actually runs a thread in parallel with the victim's thread and generally computes cache access time, so it's not what i'm talking about.

I'm more wondering about side channel attacks using for instance power monitoring, or electromagnetic attacks.

Links to research papers would be welcome.

Comment: Power and electromagnetic attacks are usually used to work out what a component like the CPU is doing rather than to try to read data in the CPU. For example if you monitor the power usage of the CPU as it performs certain cryptographic functions you can work out the number of one bits in the key. This becomes easier on a singly threaded architecture as there is less signal noise.

Comment: Cache attacks can absolutely be done on a processor with only one hardware thread. It's not like the cache is flushed as soon as a given process' timeslot is up.

Comment: @Hector Actually I recall reading a paper somewhere that SMT actually made it easier to mount power analysis attacks on processors. I forget exactly why it made it easier, but it somehow made it possible to more easily filter out environmental noise.